# How to interpret this context free language?

Tags: context-free

$S \to aAA$

$A \to aS \mid bS \mid a$

Trivial thing:

starting and ending with a

Atleast 3 a's are definitely present

(These are very layman observations...but seriously I am unable to figure out what exactly this language is all about. ...)
My attempt:

What I am able to generate

1)aaa

2)aAA

a bS A

a ba AA A

a ba ***

This suggests after b there should be atleast 1 a

*(Coz those *** have all

1. a's

or

2. if bS used then again a 'ba**'

Or

3. if aS used length also increases by atleast 3.)*

I know this is not a good analysis..and so I am not expecting any answer but would definitely expect some comments about some intuition or idea..plz any help would be much regarded..

(Although answers are always welcome ;-) )

Comment: You can eliminate $S$ to obtain the more reasonable recurrence $A \to aaAA \mid baAA \mid a$, which can be interpreted in terms of full binary trees with $aa/ba$ at internal nodes and $a$ at leaves, read in preorder. Then $S \to aAA$ describes $L(S)$ in terms of $L(A)$.